# can't login to admin panel check if admin or writer

Tags: php, mysql, web, mysqli

I hope that someone can help me with this. I try to login to admin panel with admin or writer and block the sample user to login it, but when I use this code I have some problem:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../include/config.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$_SESSION[id]' AND `role` = 'admin' OR 'writer'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) != 1) {
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    } else {
        echo '';
    }
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

This code let me to login with only admin and can't login with writer. 
And when I try to but this ('admin' OR 'writer') this also let the sample user login to admin panel, i need help to block user login to this page

Thank you.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: `x='Y' OR 'Z'` does not mean "*x* is either *y* or *z*" but instead "either *x* is *y*, or *z* is true". What you want is `x IN ('Y','Z')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note if your first condition is true then it never check your second condition in OR statement.

> Copy and use it

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$_SESSION[id]' AND `role` = 'admin' OR `role` = 'writer'");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) != 1) {
                header("Location: ../index.php");
            }else {
                echo '';
            }
        }else {
            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }
```

Comment: it's work but also `role` = 'user' can login to admin page

Comment: There's still a scary number of things wrong with this code.

Comment: I copy it , but 'admin' can't login And writer can login And user can login

Comment: you can add one more role  `OR role = 'user'`

Comment: i Need only `admin` and `writer` can login this page

Comment: remove else part, also it totally depend on your database record. could you please share ur database sample record

Comment: please mark it correct, for other user who review this conversation

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a part which in condition.
Add this to your code:

```
or `role` = 'writer'
```

So it should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$_SESSION[id]' AND `role` = 'admin' OR `role` = 'writer'
```

Answer (score 0):

The intended code for the SQL query probably is:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$_SESSION[id]' AND (`role` = 'admin' OR `role`= 'writer')");
```

**Important:** You could (and should) even improve that by using prepared statements for the session ID instead of using the value directly. Otherwise someone who finds a way to set the id can use [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) to manipulate your database in ways you would not expect.

Now back to the query:

- If you want to check a column for several possible values, you cannot just write
  `role = 'admin' OR 'writer'`, but you have to check each value individually. That means it should be `role = 'admin' OR role = 'writer'`. Otherwise the SQL server will try to evaluate `'writer'`, a string literal, as boolean value, and that does not do what one might think it does. Instead it is always true, basically making the query useless.
- An alternative for checking multiple values is the `IN` keyword. It allows for conditions like `role IN ('admin', 'writer')` and is true, if role is either 'admin' or 'writer'.
- Mixing AND and OR follows predefined [operator precedence rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html), and AND is stronger then OR. So a condition like `a AND b OR c` is true, if:

  - conditions a and b are met
  - or condition c is met. This especially means that neither a nor b must be met.

  To enforce precedence, use parenthesis: `a AND (b OR c)`

  This condition is met only if:

  - condition a is met and condition b is met
  - condition a is met and condition c is met
  - condition a is met and both condition b and c are met.